# Nested For Loops w/ If-Else

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I've never done a nested for loop before and my understanding of for loops is only rudimentary anyway. I am trying to get the loop to iterate over rows of a matrix and then elements of a vector to write to an empty matrix. I am also open to non-loop/vectorized solutions, though I would love to know why my loop code is so hopelessly broken.

To set up the input matrices and vector:

```
condition = c(0,1,2)
condition_risk = c(0,1,1,2,2,2)
condition_health = c(0,0,0,1,1,2)
ES = rnorm(n = 10)

ppt1 = matrix(sample(condition, 10, replace = T), ncol = 10, nrow = 100)
ppt2 = matrix(sample(condition_risk, 10, replace = T), ncol = 10, nrow = 25)
ppt3 = matrix(sample(condition_health, 10, replace = T), ncol = 10, nrow = 25)

key = rbind(ppt1,ppt2,ppt3)
key_recoded = matrix(NA, ncol = 10, nrow = 150)
```

This creates a vector of effects -1 to 1 called "ES"; a matrix w/ conditions 0,1,2 called "key"; and an empty matrix with the same dimensions called "key_recoded":

```
head(ES)
-0.31741374 -0.08023316 -0.57528823  0.78028852 -0.20937815  0.12266581

head(key)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[6,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2

head(key_recoded)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
[6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

The goal is to recode the conditions from 0,1,2 to 2,1,0 when ES values are negative.

For example, ES[1] = -.31741374 and key[1,1] = 2, so key_recoded [1,1] should be 0 instead of 2. If key[1,1] had instead been 0, then key_recoded would be 2 instead of 0. Condition values of 1 in "key" are to be ignored.

This is what key_recoded should look like; see that 0 and 2 re flipped from key w/ 0s in the 1st row instead of 2s:

```
head(key_recoded)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[4,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[6,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
```

This is my sad code that does nothing to the empty matrix, "key_recoded", but returns no errors:

```
for (j in nrow(key)){
  for (i in nrow(ES)){
    if(ES[i] < 0 && key[j,i] == 2){
      key_recoded[j,i] = 0
    }
    else{
      key_recoded[j,i] = key[j,i]
    }
    if(ES[i] < 0 && key[j,i] == 0){
      key_recoded[j,i] = 2
    }
    else{
      key_recoded[j,i] = key[j,i]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `for (j in 1:nrow(key))`. like you have it it's just the last row. And the same for the `i` index. Also, `nrow(ES)` returns `NULL` since `ES` is a vector, you should use `length` or the rather esoteric `NROW`.

Comment: please use `set.seed` to make these reproducible

Comment: @RuiBarradas Oops. Yeah, that's a problem. I guess I'll leave it because the solution code fixes that?

Comment: @rawr Sorry, I don't use set.seed that often. I can't get it to work to make the randomized 012 the same each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Onyambu's answer doesn't take in account if ES have negative value:

```
key2 <- key
for(i in 1:length(ES)){
  if(ES[i] < 0){
    key2[,i] <- ifelse(key2[,i] == 2, 0, ifelse(key2[,i] == 0, 2, key2[,i]))
  }
}
head(key)
head(key2)
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It should only swap 2s & 0s when ES is negative. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
ES
 [1] -0.30114431 -0.97900009  1.04164231  0.64237371  0.44924653
 [6]  0.24134990 -0.20286873  0.49661435  0.30273617  0.05852534
 n=which(ES<0)
 key_recorded=key #Create a duplicate of key and store it in key_recorded
 key_recorded[,n][key[,n]==2]=0# Store 0 in key_recorded wherever key is 2
 key_recorded[,n][key[,n]==0]=2# Store 2 in key_recorded wherever key is 0
 head(key)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[4,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[6,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2
 head(key_recorded)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    2    2    0    0    0    0    2    0    0     0
[2,]    0    0    2    2    2    2    0    2    2     2
[3,]    2    2    0    0    0    0    2    0    0     0
[4,]    0    0    2    2    2    2    0    2    2     2
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[6,]    0    0    2    2    2    2    0    2    2     2
```

Now as you can see the required columns are flipped when ES<0 but when ES>=0, the columns are maintained

Comment: For beginners, it might be more helpful to think of these operations as: *for every position in `key` where the value is `2`, set the corresponding value in `key_recorded` to `0`*. For the purposes here, R really doesn't care what the values in `key_recorded` are, so saying "replace" could be confusing even if that is what ends up happening because of the first assignment.

Comment: I like that  this gets rid of the for loop, but it needs to only be when ES is negative. I can't just swap all of the 0s for 2s.

Comment: Ohh maybe I misunderstood your question. will fix that in a moment

Comment: sorry you used the term `nrow(ES)` but ES is not a matrix!!

Comment: @Onyambu Wow, that's so much better than a loop! How did you know it didn't need one? I'm trying to understand for future reference in case I run into a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @SKOR2 well one should try and avoid loops as much as possible. and only deal with vector manipulation. Only use the loops when unable to avoid them. But if working with Rcpp, then you can use loops as much as you want.